# Update variable and send it to another class in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

i'm new at kivy and python.So have a question.
Writing a little countdown app where you set time with + and -. First part, where I change time by +,- works fine, but somehow i need to send a countdown variable to countdown function(which isn't done yet).
After I press + or - StringProperty and label updates,but countdown variable not.
Need some help with it.Thank you.

.py file

```
import datetime
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, BooleanProperty, Clock, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Window.size = (520, 1000)

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class SettingWindow(Screen):
    pass
class TimeWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class BoxLayout_1(BoxLayout):
    countdown = 180
    min ,sec = divmod(countdown, 60)
    time_round_text = StringProperty(f'{min:02d}:{sec:02d}')
    def minus_minute(self):
        if self.countdown > 10:
            self.countdown = self.countdown - 10
            self.min, self.sec = divmod(self.countdown, 60)
            self.time_round_text = f'{self.min:02d}:{self.sec:02d}'
        else:
            self.countdown = 0
            self.time_round_text = "Select amount of time!"
        
    def plus_minute(self):
        if self.countdown < 600:
            self.countdown = self.countdown + 10
            self.min, self.sec = divmod(self.countdown, 60)
            self.time_round_text = f'{self.min:02d}:{self.sec:02d}'
        else:
            self.countdown = 610
            self.time_round_text = "Maximum time selected!"
        

class BoxLayout_2(BoxLayout):
#Countdown function here
#Need somehow to get countdown variable after all changes

class TheTimerApp(App):
    pass

TheTimerApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
WindowManager:
    MainWindow:
    SettingWindow:
    TimeWindow:
<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    BoxLayout_1:
<BoxLayout_1>:
    orientation:"vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Settings"
            font_size: "20dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
            size_hint: .5 , 1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 1}
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "setting"
                app.root.transition.direction = "right"
        Label:
            text:"Simple Timer"
            font_size: "20dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text:"-"
            on_press: root.minus_minute()
            font_size: "40dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
        Label:
            text:"Time"
            font_size: "30dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
        Button:
            text:"+"
            on_press: root.plus_minute()
            font_size: "40dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"

    Label:
        text: root.time_round_text
        color: 106, 90, 205
        font_size: "30dp"
        font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"

    Button:
        text:"START"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "time"
            app.root.transition.direction = "left"
        size_hint: 1 , 2
        font_size: "50dp"
        font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"


<SettingWindow>:
    name: "setting"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text:"Go back"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "main"
                app.root.transition.direction = "left"
            font_size: "20dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
            size_hint: 1, .2
        Label:
            font_size: "20dp"
            font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
            text:"Enable and Disable Dark Mode"
        Switch:
            text:"Dark"


<TimeWindow>:
    name:"time"
    BoxLayout_2:
<BoxLayout_2>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text:"Go back"
        font_size: "20dp"
        font_name: "fonts/Digital dream Fat Narrow.ttf"
        size_hint: 1, .2
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "main"
            app.root.transition.direction = "right"
    Button:
        text: #Countdown here
        on_press: #countdown function here
        font_name: "fonts/Digital-7.ttf"
        size_hint: 1, 2
        color: 0, 0, 1
        font_size: 80
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the many ways to achieve that is the following :

1. First add an [`id`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#ids) (for a weak reference) in `kvlang` to your target widget, here `BoxLayout_1`.

```py
<MainWindow>:
    name:"main"
    BoxLayout_1:
        id: box1
```

2. Now bind a method say, `countdown_func` to the button.

```py
<BoxLayout_2>:
    ...
    Button:
        text: 
        on_press: root.countdown_func(self) # Pass the button instance if you need it.
        font_name: "fonts/Digital-7.ttf"
```

3. Access the target values accordingly in that method of `BoxLayout_2`.

```py
class BoxLayout_2(BoxLayout):

    def countdown_func(self, btn):
        # Here 'btn' is the reference of the button you passed.
        # First access the running app's instance.
        app = App.get_running_app()
        # Access the screen where your target widget is.
        main_screen = app.root.get_screen("main") # Since ScreenManager is your root.
        # Now access the target widget and its property.
        countdown = main_screen.ids.box1.countdown
        # Now say, you want to change the text of the button 'btn'.
        btn.text = str(countdown)
```

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, now i understand.